# How to pop and return the top element of a stack in scala

Tags: scala, list, stack

Hi I am trying to pop off the top element in a stack in some Scala code I'm writing but the `pop` function for the in built Stack class returns the whole Stack minus the top element, which is not what I'm after.

It also seems that the recommended way to implement a Stack in Scala is to use a `List` and then use `tail` and `::` as `pop` and `push`. `tail` also returns a list minus the "top" element.

How can it be done so that the element is returned so it can be stored in a variable?

EDIT

I have this code to demonstrate what is happening:

```
sealed trait Symbol {
    def withType(): String
    def withValue(): String
}

class Lexer extends LexerTokeniser[Symbol] {

    case class Element(typeOf: String, value: String) extends Symbol {
        override def withType(): String = typeOf
        override def withValue(): String = value
    }

    private val controlStack = Stack[Element](Element("String", "s")) 

    val topEl = controlStack.pop // This sets topEl to type Stack[Element]
    val newTopEl = topEl.withValue() // This is an error, no such function
}
```

Comment: From the ScalaDocs page for [collection.mutable.Stack](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Stack.html#pop():A): `def pop(): A` "Removes the top element from this stack and return it". It appears that your understanding of the `pop()` method is faulty. Perhaps you could post some code that _doesn't_ do what you want.

Comment: I have added what I have written and shown the problems in comments in the code. Thanks

Comment: I was not able to recreate the error you describe. In order to get your example to compile I made sure that `Stack` refers to `collection.mutable.Stack`. It now compiles and runs for me without error. What are the `import`s you're using?

Comment: Brilliant thanks that is working now. Can you elaborate on why it was returning the Stack[Element] type before it was made mutable please? Many thanks for the help :)

Comment: Because you were using other kind of Stack probably

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

val stack = Stack[String]("a","b","c")

val popped = stack.pop

println(popped)// a
```

This is what you want, I think you were confusing tail with pop.

Comment: I have added some code to highlight what I am seeing. I am not getting an Element type back but a type of Stack[Element]. This doesn't coincide with your explanation (which is what I want it to do)